# how to create yes to all option in dialog box through swing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, joptionpane

I want to create a dialog box which contain four button

1. yes
2. no
3. yes to all
4. cancel

I'm able to create dialog but I am unable to add action in yes to all button.

```
Object[] options = {"Yes", "No", "Yes To All", "Cancel"};
int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(MainGui.appView, "file "+tempFile+ 
              "exits.\n Do you wish to overwrite?", "Question", 
              JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
              null, options, options[2]);
```

Comment: by looking at your acepted rate only http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button and http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/OptionPane.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for value of `n`. It will be as follows:

```
n --> button
-----------
0 --> Yes
1 --> No
2 --> Yes to all
3 --> Cancel
```

You can switch over `n` and do action respectively.